# Possibility of using Generic function to convert any Java Object to JSON

Tags: java, json

I would like to know if it is possible to convert any Java object to JSON object. Currently I have the following code.

```
JSONArray data = new JSONArray();
for (User user : users) {
            JSONArray row = new JSONArray();
            row.put(user.getId()).put(user.getUserName()).put(user.isEnabled());
            data.put(row);
        }
```

The current issue is different object (e.g. User and Admin) will have different property, thus the above code will work for other object. I am thinking of putting a similar code in my GenericHibernateDAO in order to automatically convert any list into a json list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can serialize your java object to json object. There are n number of library is available ex `gson, jettyson, flexjson` etc.

[GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/) example -

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Collection<Integer> ints = Lists.immutableList(1,2,3,4,5);

(Serialization)
String json = gson.toJson(ints); ==> json is [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here i exemplify the way of converting POJO to json using jackson

1. create your pojo : User user = new User();
2. you can set or get values to/from user
3. create ObjectMapper : ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
4. String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(user);// object to json